# How can i check for hash pin to show when submitting the input button and to display Not found when not finding?

Tags: php, html

How can I check for hash pin to show when submitting the input button and to display Not found when not finding?

Here is my code

Debug Output:

```
<?php

$goodtext = "Not found";
$error = false;
// $md5 = false;
$code = "";
// If there is no parameter, this code is all skipped
if (isset($_GET['md5'])) {
    $time_pre = microtime(true);
    $hash = $_GET['md5'];

    $show = 15;

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 9999; $i++) {
        $str = $i. '';

        if (strlen($str) == 1) {
            $str = '000'.$str;
        }
        else if (strlen($str) == 2) {
            $str = '00'.$str;
        }
        else if (strlen($str) == 3) {
            $str = '0'.$str;
        }
        $check = hash('md5', '1234');
        if ($check == $str) {
            $goodtext = $str;
            break;   // Exit the inner loop
        }
        $check = hash('md5', 1234);
        if ($check == $str) {
            $error = $str;
            break;
        }
        // Debug output until $show hits 0
        if ($show > 0) {
            print "$check $str\n";
            $show = $show - 1;
        }

    }

    //Compute elapsed time
    $time_post = microtime(true);
    print "Elapsed time: ";
    print $time_post - $time_pre;
    print "\n";
}

?>

<!--Use the very short syntax and call htmlentities()-- >
<p>PIN: Here is where I'd like to display the results PIN number of Not Found when it's the case.
</p>
<form method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="md5" size="40" />
    <input type="submit" value="Crack MD5" />
</form>
```

I'm new to php and starting to learn, but I can't manage this to
display the pin form $i ($i  i guess) or Not found as default or when
it doesn't match the hash pin.

Here are the hashes :

```
0bd65e799153554726820ca639514029 = 4429
aa36c88c27650af3b9868b723ae15dfc = 4413 
1ca906c1ad59db8f11643829560bab55 = Not found
1d8d70dddf147d2d92a634817f01b239 = 4427
acf06cdd9c744f969958e1f085554c8b = 3341 
81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055 = 1234
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
<?php

$goodtext = "Not found";
$error = false;
// $md5 = false;
$code = "";
// If there is no parameter, this code is all skipped
if (isset($_GET['md5'])) {
    $time_pre = microtime(true);
    $hash = $_GET['md5'];

    $show = 15;

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 9999; $i++) {
        $str = $i . '';

        if (strlen($str) == 1) {
            $str = '000'.$str;
        }
        else if (strlen($str) == 2) {
            $str = '00'.$str;
        }
        else if (strlen($str) == 3) {
            $str = '0'.$str;
        }

        $check = hash('md5', $str);

        // Debug output until $show hits 0
        if ($show > 0) {
            print "$check $str<br />";
            $show = $show - 1;
        }

        if ($check == $hash) {
            $goodtext = $str;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($goodtext == "Not found") {
        print $goodtext."<br />";
    }
    else {
        print "PIN is: ".$goodtext."<br />";
    }

    //Compute elapsed time
    $time_post = microtime(true);
    print "Elapsed time: ";
    print $time_post - $time_pre;
    print "<br />";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you , that is really good it works , but now i have to display that inside that <p> tag